# I need to evaluate the integral $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^{15}}\,dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> I need to evaluate the integral
>   $$\int_2^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^{15}}\,dx$$

I tried integration by substitution but cant get the $x$ term to cancel, so im kind of stuck, any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried integration by parts  ?

Comment: HInt:$$\int x^m\ln x dx =\dfrac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}\ln x-\int \dfrac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}.\dfrac1x dx $$

Answer (score 2):

*Alternatively*, one may start with
$$
\int_2^{\infty}  \frac1{x^{s}}\: dx=\frac1{(s-1)\cdot2^{s-1}},\qquad s>1,
$$ then one is allowed to differentiate with respect to $s$ under the integral sign to get
$$
\int_2^{\infty}  -\frac{\ln x}{x^{s}}\: dx=\left(\frac1{(s-1)\cdot2^{s-1}} \right)',\qquad s>1,
$$ that is
$$
\int_2^{\infty}  \frac{\ln x}{x^{s}}\: dx=\frac1{(s-1)^2\cdot2^{s-1}}+\frac{\ln 2}{(s-1)\cdot2^{s-1}},\qquad s>1,
$$ putting $s=15$ gives

> $$
> \int_2^{\infty}  \frac{\ln x}{x^{15}}\: dx=\frac{1}{3\:211\:264}+\frac{\ln  2}{229\:376}.
> $$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:Integration by parts gives
$$\left(-\frac{x^{-14}}{14}\cdot\ln x\right)_2^{\infty}+\frac{1}{14}\int_2^{\infty} x^{-15}dx$$

Comment: thanks, i have no idea why i havent thought of that :)

Comment: is it possible that the +14 before the the integral sign is supposed to be + 1/14 ?

Comment: @dvd280...Sorry ..I missed it..I was going to edit it when my browser crashed

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_2^{\infty} \log x  \cdot x^{-15} dx$$

Integration by parts,

$$= \left[ \log x \cdot \frac{x^{-14}}{-14}\right]_2^{\infty} - \int_2^{\infty} \frac 1x \cdot \frac{x^{-14}}{-14}dx$$

$$= \left[ \log x \cdot \frac{x^{-14}}{-14}\right]_2^{\infty} - \int_2^{\infty} \frac{x^{-15}}{-14}dx$$

$$= \left[ \log x \cdot \frac{x^{-14}}{-14}\right]_2^{\infty} -  \left[\frac{x^{-14}}{-14 \cdot -14}\right]_2^{\infty}$$

Can you proceed further?

Comment: Sorry actually because of using on mobile I can't see formatted output. Thank u for spotting my mistake.